# WCF Business Objects Design using Interfaces

Tags: web-services, wcf, soa, entities

Our project requires us to interact with multiple sources for information like Oracle DB, SalesForce, etc. So we want to wrap all the calls under a WCF layer, so that anybody inside the company can use it. For implementing the Domain Objects, this is a consideration:

```
public class NoteTypeA : INote, INoteTypeA {}
public class NoteTypeB : INote, INoteTypeB {}
public class Customer : INote, ICustomer {}
```

All the Note classes such as NoteTypeA, NoteTypeB, NoteTypeC all would inherit from INote, however they also would Inherit from INoteTypeA, in the case of NoteTypeA.

I agree with the idea of using INote as it helps you implement Multiple Inheritance. But I don't get the reason behind using INoteTypeA and its looks like [anti-pattern](http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2009/05/09/entity-interface-anti-pattern/) for me.

What do you guys think? 
Does that protect me from a future change? 
Does it help me smoothly add an out of scope change?

Answer (score 0):

I think will be largely subjective and depend on the implementation.

I usually don't make interfaces for my classes if they are just data containers, but if they have business logic functions, then I do.

Comment: Thank you. Regarding protection from future changes, If i write methods to return Interfaces instead of concrete classes. Would that really give me any benefit of using Interfaces?

Comment: @sunny24365 - If your WCF methods return interfaces, they will come across the wire as `object`, as an interface doesn't contain data.  That means the client will have to know the interface in order to properly cast the returned data.  This is easily done with shared assemblies, but that might be something you don't want to do, depending on your business requirements.  I would advise against returning interfaces if at all possible, and return concrete types.

Comment: @Tim - If that's the case, then i don't see a reason why i even need to create INoteTypeA, INoteTypeB Interfaces in the example above. Correct?